# Android PopupWindow window focus/selection

Tags: android, focus, selection, android-edittext, popupwindow

In my app,I have an edittext and a PopupWindow.
I want to show the popup once the user starts editing the text. but when I show the popup, it graps the focus from the edittext, and the virtual keyboard is dismissed (and I want it shown).

I tried creating the popup as not focusable, but then I can't select it after it's shown.

I also tried changing the focus and selection attributes of both edittext and from code after and before the popup is shown, but if the popup is created as not focusable, I can't select it after it's shown.

Is there a way of displaying a selectable popup along with editing the edittext?

Answer (score 0):

You could try going in other direction. you have to control the input method editor (IME). every editable has an appropriate IME (also edittext has). You can control the IME - for example to be shown all the time not regarding to the state of edittext and dismiss it when you click on something or something happen.
You can ovveride the default editext implementation or you can control the IME at the viewgroup container/activity level.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html (read the APIs for controlling IMEs at the end).

hope this will help.